# Adding a Simulator in xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, ios-simulator

I am new to macOS and xcode. So forgive my ignorance.

I am trying to add a new  iOS simulator in xcode. I am running version 15.0.1 and macOS of the latest Ventura.

Here are the instructions I am following:
Adding a Simulator
In Xcode, from the menu bar, choose Window > Devices and Simulators.

Choose Simulators at the top of the sidebar.

Click the Add button (+) in the lower left corner.

Choose a Device Type and OS Version for your simulator, and optionally provide it with a name.

Click Create to create the new simulator.

All of that works and I click create and it silently does nothing. No new simulators appear. No errors. I am confused. If I create the same simulator with the same name it doesn't warn me about overwriting.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score -2):

Looks like Xcode is silently accepting a command and providing zero feedback as to whether it passed or failed. Even when writing the same simulator out.  So all simulators were created - they just don't show up on the screen where you add them. You can find them when you open simulators for a particular simulator run time.  The problem now is that expo doesn't give me an option to add my app to these new simulators - but that is a different question for a different day.

Comment: "We can close this"—you can [accept your own answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/248627), but that doesn't close the question. Other users can still post new answers. Questions generally get closed if they're not appropriate for Stack Overflow, not when they get answered. The [tour] gives some good background on how things work here.